# Rare Characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I am working whit a great deal of rare Characters inside Javascript characters like     **'èéêëēėẹěəæεɛ'**, and im storing them inside a array but for some reason javascript can't recognize them and puts alot of **question marks** where it cant recognize them i have:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

included on the page but when ever i just `Alert (èéêëēėẹěəæεɛ');` i get results like "����eeeeee�???" and even when i copy paste the characters in the array they end up like this **'èéêëeee?e?æe?'** some of them are missing.

Could anyone tell me what i am missing so i can store these characters so that they remain in the array like **'èéêëēėẹěəæεɛ'** this and they get displayed also out like that.

Comment: Make sure that your source is actually UTF8.

Comment: You mean delete the "-" ? i did but still displays ����eeeeee�??? on alert

Comment: No; I mean check what encoding your file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web browsers determine the character encoding of a webpage via:

- if loaded from the filesytem, use the `<meta charset`
- if loaded from a url:

  - if an http header exists that specifies the charset, use it. done.
  - else look for a  `<meta charset`

most web servers send an http header that specifies the encoding/characterset. You need to configure it to send the correct one, which is utf-8(assuming your text editor really is configured to save the file as utf-8). The important take away of the decidion process is that a web browser generally ignores your meta tag because your webserver sends a real http header, and the real http headers takes precedence.

Comment: Ok here is what i have done it seems that it is working aperently now.. I made Encoding->Encode in UTF-8 without BOM and i copy pasted the 'èéêëēėẹěəæεɛ' again and now its displaying it like how i want it but did this resolve for all browsers?

Comment: yes you did, as long as your web server sends either no charset http header at all, or it sends the correct utf8 one. otherwise, your results will be unreliable.

Comment: I checked in Chrome and IE 6 to and works fine :D il go look if it works on my brothers PC and if it does then i will accept your answer brb